# How does the odds of rolling at least 1 success change if Skill Grid nodes change from "+2 TN" to "+1 TN -1 Dice"?

Tags: statistics, shadowrun, shadowrun-sr2

The skill tree is brutal. For those who don't know, In Shadowrun 2nd edition, you can use skills you don't have by defaulting it from a skill or attribute you have by moving through the diagram shown below. Each dot is a node and you add +2 to the TN of the test. You cannot move backward through an arrow, though. You cannot use Charisma to roll Psychology, for example.

3 nodes and you need to open the D6 one more time to get a success. No wonder it was gone in SR3 and beyond.

I have a group that wants to play good old SR2. I think I want to change the skill grid node penalty from +2 TN to +1 TN and -1 base pool dice. If your base pool drops to zero, you cannot roll.

Meaning, with a Quickness of 5, an elf could use Firearms with a dice pool of 3 and a +2 to TN instead of rolling 5 dice with a +4 TN penalty.

A human with a six in Intelligence still wouldn't be able to use Military Theory, as there's six nodes between them and they would lose all six dice. The default would be to suffer a +12 to the TN, which meant opening the D6 twice.

[image: Skill tree diagram. (c) Fasa and its successors. Important to illustrate the question. If not in compliance to fair use rules, feel free to delete this link.]

(opening a die means that if you roll the maximum value, you roll again and add. In this scenario, one needs to roll a six twice and then beat the TN in the third roll. The odds of rolling two sixes in a row is 1/36).

I intend to make defaulting to skills easier. I feel the change might make the grid easier to use. But how easier does it get?

My AnyDice-fu is not nearly enough to model this. The answer does not need to use AnyDice, in any case. I even avoided tagging it as so.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the basics: you roll a number of six-sided dice equal to your skill, with each roll above or equal to the target number (TN) counting as one success?

Comment: JIKES! I remember that page!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The poor get poorer, the rich get <s>richer</s> less poor

If the character's situation had many nodes / few dice before this change, the chances get worse; if they had few nodes / many dice, the chances get better (though obviously still worse than not having a penalty at all).

#### Asymptotic analysis

Every +6 TN multiplies the chance of a die succeeding by a factor of 1/6 (and +12 TN by a factor of 1/36 and so on). So, as a rule of thumb, you should be willing to multiply the size of your dice pool by a factor as severe as

$$6^{-\frac{n}{6}} \approx 0.742^n$$

in exchange for a decrease of \$n\$ in the TN, which is what you are doing when switching to the new scheme while passing through \$n\$ nodes. Since all the parameters are integers, we can just loop through all possibilities to find, for each starting pool size and number of nodes, which scheme is more favorable.

| Starting pool size | New more favorable | Original more favorable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | never | 1 or more nodes |
| 3 | never | 1 or more nodes |
| 4 | 1 node | 2 or more nodes |
| 5 | 2 or fewer nodes | 3 or more nodes |
| 6 | 4 or fewer nodes | 5 or more nodes |
| 7 | 5 or fewer nodes | 6 or more nodes |

For pools larger than 7 dice, the new scheme is more favorable as long as you don't lose literally all your dice: higher TNs become exponentially more difficult, whereas losing all your dice save one is only a linear loss.

#### Errors in this approximation

This approximation is a geometric mean over a uniform distribution of TNs modulo 6. Of course, the TN probability curve is not a perfect straight line on a log scale. So individual cases may vary somewhat depending on the base TN. For example, your elf loses out giving up 2 out of 5 dice in exchange for TN 8 -> 6, but TN 6 -> 4 is a big win.

[image: Chance of reaching TN with a single die, log scale.]
[*Chance of reaching TN with a single die.*](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/icecup.html?p=ge&ls=on&c=GYJw9gtgBAlgxgUwA5jAG1hFIAuUAmAUGAK45JkAU+lAbAJQB0CAHkmmPgtcjgBYBeAKz16hIA)

The mean number of successes in a pool also overestimates the chance of scoring *at least* one success. However, the situation where a character lacks an appropriate skill probably tends towards a low chance of multiple successes, which decreases this source of error.

#### Potential alternative

If you like this effect, great; if you don't like this effect, you could reduce the penalty to just +1 TN per node. If this is too drastic you could dilute it by adding a few more nodes to the tree.

Answer (score 2):

#### When is +1 TN / -1 dice better than +2 TN?

First, a slight change of perspective.  An equivalent question to the above, which I will try to answer below, is:

> "If given the choice, when (if ever) would you rather give up one die than take +1 TN?"

In effect, we're just looking at the situation after already having taken +1 TN and trying to decide whether it would be better to *also* take -1 dice or *another* +1 TN.

---

When rolling \$n\$ dice against TN = \$x\$, the average **expected number of successes** is \$E(n, x) = n \cdot p(x)\$ and the probability of scoring **at least one success** is \$P(n, x) = 1 - (1 - p(x))^n\$, where \$p(x)\$ is the success probability when rolling one die against TN = \$x\$.

It also turns out to be useful to define the function \$d(x) = p(x+1) - p(x)\$, which represents the reduction in the single-die success probability \$p(x)\$ when going from TN = \$x\$ to TN = \$x+1\$, or equivalently the probability of rolling exactly \$x\$ on a single (exploding / opening) d6.

The functions \$p(x)\$ and \$d(x)\$ are somewhat complicated due to quirks of the "open" / "exploding" d6 mechanic:

[image: Figure 1]
(Figure 1: An approximate graph of \$p(x)\$ [plotted with AnyDice](https://anydice.com/program/346f2/graph/at_least).)

[image: Figure 2]
(Figure 2: An approximate graph of \$d(x) = p(x) - p(x+1)\$ also [plotted with AnyDice](https://anydice.com/program/346f2/graph).)

In particular, we can see that \$d(x) = 0\$ whenever \$x\$ is a multiple of 6, since it's not actually possible to roll a multiple of 6 on an exploding d6!

Still, we *can* actually give explicit (piecewise) formulas for \$p(x)\$ and \$d(x)\$.  For this, it's convenient to write \$x = 6k + r\$, where \$q\$ is the number of times a 6 is rolled on the die and \$r\$ is the result of the final roll (which, for mathematical purposes, we'll allow to take values from 1 to 6, even though a final roll of 6 *should* always result in a reroll).  This lets us write the formulas for \$p(x)\$ and \$d(x)\$ like this:

$$\begin{aligned}
p(6k + r) &= \frac{7-r}{6^{k+1}} \\
d(6k + r) &= \begin{cases}
1 \mathbin/ 6^{k+1} & \text{if}\ r \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} \\
0 & \text{if}\ r = 6 \\
\end{cases}
\end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

These formulas will come handy later.

---

With that digression out of the way, let's do some math!

**If all you care about is the expected number of successes**, giving up one die is better than taking +1 TN whenever:

$$\begin{aligned} E(n-1, x) > E(n, x+1)
\iff& (n-1) \cdot p(x) > n \cdot p(x+1) \\
\iff& p(x) < n \cdot d(x),
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

This makes intuitive sense: giving up one die means you lose the expected number \$p(x)\$ of successes that you would've rolled on that die, while taking +1 TN means your expected number of successes for each of the \$n\$ dice goes down by \$d(x)\$.

Now, as noted above, \$d(x) = 0\$ whenever \$x\$ is a multiple of 6.  This means that it's *always* better to take +1 TN than to give up one die if the TN is a multiple of 6!  Or, equivalently, +2 TN is always better than +1 TN / -1 dice whenever the TN is *one less than* a multiple of 6.

That special case aside, whenever \$x\$ is not a multiple of 6, we always have \$d(x) > 0\$ and thus condition \$(2)\$ above can be rewritten as:

$$n > \frac{p(x)}{d(x)} \tag{3}$$

In other words, **giving up one die is better than taking +1 TN whenever you have sufficiently many dice (and the TN isn't a multiple of 6).**

How many dice is sufficiently many?  Using the formulas from \$(1)\$ above and assuming \$1 ≤ r ≤ 5\$, we can see that $$p(x) \mathbin/ d(x) = p(6k + r) \mathbin/ d(6k + r) = 7-r.$$  In other words, giving up one die yields a higher expected number of successes than taking +1 TN whenever \$r ≠ 6\$ and \$n > 7 - r\$.  (If \$n = 7 - r\$, taking either -1 dice or +1 TN both give exactly the same expected number of successes!)

Here's the same result conveniently tabulated:

| TN = | -1 dice is at least as good as +1 TN when… |
| --- | --- |
| \$6k + 1\$ | …you have at least 6 dice. |
| \$6k + 2\$ | …you have at least 5 dice. |
| \$6k + 3\$ | …you have at least 4 dice. |
| \$6k + 4\$ | …you have at least 3 dice. |
| \$6k + 5\$ | …you have at least 2 dice. |
| \$6k + 6\$ | …never. |

---

What if we care more about the **probability of rolling at least one success** instead?  In that case, giving up one die is better than taking +1 TN whenever:

$$\begin{aligned} P(n-1, x) > P(n, x+1)
\iff& 1 - (1 - p(x))^{n-1} > 1 - (1 - p(x+1))^n \\
\iff& (1 - p(x))^{n-1} < (1 - p(x+1))^n \\
\iff& \frac{(1 - p(x))^{n-1}}{(1 - p(x))^n} < \frac{(1 - p(x+1))^n}{(1 - p(x))^n} \\
\iff& \frac{1}{1 - p(x)} < \left( \frac{1 - p(x+1)}{1 - p(x)} \right)^n \\
\iff& 1 - p(x) > \left( \frac{1 - p(x)}{1 - p(x+1)} \right)^n \\
\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

Again, whenever \$x\$ is a multiple of 6, \$p(x) = p(x+1)\$, and thus this condition reduces to \$1 - p(x) > 1\$, which is impossible.  Thus, as concluded above, **taking +1 TN is always the better choice when the current TN is a multiple of 6**, since it has no (immediate) down side.

When \$x\$ is *not* a multiple of 6, things are more complicated, but we can find the lowest exponent \$n\$ for which \$(4)\$ holds by taking the logarithm of both sides:

$$\begin{aligned} P(n-1, x) > P(n, x+1)
\iff& 1 - p(x) > \left( \frac{1 - p(x)}{1 - p(x+1)} \right)^n \\
\iff& \log(1 - p(x)) > n \log\left( \frac{1 - p(x)}{1 - p(x+1)} \right) \\
\iff& \frac1n < 1 - \frac{\log(1 - p(x+1))}{\log(1 - p(x))} \\
\iff& n > \left( 1 - \frac{\log(1 - p(x+1))}{\log(1 - p(x))} \right)^{-1} \\
\end{aligned}$$

The right-hand side looks like a mess, but it's an expression that we can calculate.  Here's a table of what it looks like for TN = \$x\$ ranging from 1 to 48:

| TN | \$1/n <\$ | \$n >\$ |  | TN | \$1/n <\$ | \$n >\$ |  | TN | \$1/n <\$ | \$n >\$ |  | TN | \$1/n <\$ | \$n >\$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 | 1.00 |  | 13 | 0.17 | 5.93 |  | 25 | 0.17 | 6.00 |  | 37 | 0.17 | 6.00 |
| 2 | 0.39 | 2.58 |  | 14 | 0.20 | 4.95 |  | 26 | 0.20 | 5.00 |  | 38 | 0.20 | 5.00 |
| 3 | 0.37 | 2.71 |  | 15 | 0.25 | 3.97 |  | 27 | 0.25 | 4.00 |  | 39 | 0.25 | 4.00 |
| 4 | 0.42 | 2.41 |  | 16 | 0.33 | 2.99 |  | 28 | 0.33 | 3.00 |  | 40 | 0.33 | 3.00 |
| 5 | 0.55 | 1.82 |  | 17 | 0.50 | 2.00 |  | 29 | 0.50 | 2.00 |  | 41 | 0.50 | 2.00 |
| 6 | 0.00 | ∞ |  | 18 | 0.00 | ∞ |  | 30 | 0.00 | ∞ |  | 42 | 0.00 | ∞ |
| 7 | 0.18 | 5.56 |  | 19 | 0.17 | 5.99 |  | 31 | 0.17 | 6.00 |  | 43 | 0.17 | 6.00 |
| 8 | 0.21 | 4.71 |  | 20 | 0.20 | 4.99 |  | 32 | 0.20 | 5.00 |  | 44 | 0.20 | 5.00 |
| 9 | 0.26 | 3.83 |  | 21 | 0.25 | 4.00 |  | 33 | 0.25 | 4.00 |  | 45 | 0.25 | 4.00 |
| 10 | 0.34 | 2.91 |  | 22 | 0.33 | 3.00 |  | 34 | 0.33 | 3.00 |  | 46 | 0.33 | 3.00 |
| 11 | 0.51 | 1.97 |  | 23 | 0.50 | 2.00 |  | 35 | 0.50 | 2.00 |  | 47 | 0.50 | 2.00 |
| 12 | 0.00 | ∞ |  | 24 | 0.00 | ∞ |  | 36 | 0.00 | ∞ |  | 48 | 0.00 | ∞ |

Looking at this table, we can see that for high TN it doesn't matter if we're interested in maximizing the expected number of successes or the probability of getting at least one success.  This makes intuitive sense: the probability of rolling *more than one* success becomes negligible when the TN is high (and the number of dice *not* too high), so that \$P(n, x) ≈ E(n, x)\$.

In fact, for all TN ≥ 4, the answer to the question "should I take -1 dice or +1 TN?" is the same regardless of which goal you're optimizing: either way, **-1 dice is at least as good as +1 TN whenever TN is not a multiple of 6 and dice + (TN modulo 6) ≥ 7.**

For low TN, however, there is a difference:

- If TN = 1, all dice will succeed.  Thus, as long as you have more than one die, giving up of your dice still gives you a guaranteed success, whereas taking +1 TN would risk rolling all ones and failing.  (Of course, if you've *already* taken +1 TN and are trying to decide between -1 dice or *another* +1 TN, this case is not relevant.)
- If TN = 2, giving up a die instead of taking +1 TN will maximize the expected number of successes if you have at least *five* dice, but will maximize the probability of at least one success if you have at least *three* dice.
- If TN = 3, giving up a die instead of taking +1 TN will maximize the expected number of successes if you have at least *four* dice, but will maximize the probability of at least one success if you have at least three dice.

Basically, these are the cases where even players with a fairly small number of dice have a high chance of rolling multiple successes, so that if you only need one success, giving up one die ends up being less of a disadvantage than increasing the TN.

---

Of course, if you're passing multiple grid nodes, you really should consider the cumulative effects of multiple increases in TN and (possible) decreases in the dice count.  In principle, these can be calculated the same way as I showed above, but this answer is getting quite long already.

In any case, the general conclusion — ignoring the funny behavior when the TN crosses a multiple of 6 — agrees with [HighDiceRoller's asymptoptic analysis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/210334): **taking -1 dice instead of +1 TN is advantageous for players with many dice** and (often) disadvantageous for players with few dice.

(In particular, while I haven't actually done the calculations, I'm *pretty sure* that the weird behavior at multiples of 6 (mostly) disappears when comparing -\$N\$ dice vs. +\$N\$ TN for \$N ≥ 2\$.  The reason why it happens is that +1 TN is essentially free when the current TN is a multiple of 6, but for +2 TN that no longer happens at any TN.)